# Linear Operators and Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space and define the operators $T, \space G:V\rightarrow V$ over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{F}$, with char($\mathbb{F})=0$. Suppose that $T^n=0$, $\text{null}(T) = 1$, and  $GT- TG = T.$ Prove that the eigenvalues of $G$ are of the form
$\alpha,$ $\alpha -1, \alpha-2, \dots, \alpha-(n-1)$,
for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$.

My attempt:

By assumption, $\text{null}(T)=1$, so there exists a nonzero vector $v \in \text{ker}(T)$. Clearly,
$0= T(v)=(GT- TG)(v) \Rightarrow T(G(v))=0 \Rightarrow G(v) \in \text{ker}(T)$ which implies that $\text{ker}(T)$ is *$G$-invariant*.

Let $u$ be an eigenvector of $G$, then $G(u) = \lambda u$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ and we have that  $(GT - TG)(u) = T(u) \Rightarrow G(T(u)) = (\lambda+1)T(u)$.

Therefore, if $u$ is eigenvector of $G$, with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $T(u)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $(\lambda+1)$.

But I don't know what I will do with this..

Comment: Almost an engaging problem--I say almost because something ain't quite right, to wit:  $\dim_F V = n$, but the alleged eigenvalues of $G$, $\alpha$, $\alpha - 1$, $\alpha - 2$, $\ldots$, $\alpha - n$ are $n + 1$ in number; but an operator on an $n$ dimensional vector space has at most $n$ eigenvalues.  Somethings gotta give, but what?  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You're nearly there.  Slight correction: suppose that $u$ is an eigenvector of $G$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Then, as you calculated, we find that
$$
G(T(u)) = (\lambda+1)T(u)
$$
That is, we have two possibilities: either $T(u)$ is an eigenvector of $G$ associated with $\lambda+1$ **or** $T(u) = 0$, which is to say that $T(u) \in \ker G$.  Because $\operatorname{null}(T) = 1$, we can deduce that $T(u) = 0$ will happen for exactly one eigenvector of $G$.

Comment: Note: this result is important in the study of [semisimple Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra)

Comment: Hello. Doesn't that mean that for each own vector $u$ of $ $, $T(u) = 0$? Do you mean that $\ ker T$ is generated by one of the eigenvectors of $G$? In addition, will the other eigenvectors of $G$ take the form $T(a)$?

Comment: @PaulichenT Not necessarily. There can be eigenvectors $u_1,u_2$ of $G$ such that $u_1$ satisfies $G(u_1) = \lambda u_1$, $T(u_1) \neq 0$, $G(T(u_1)) = (\lambda + 1)T(u_1)$ but $u_2$ satisfies $G(u_2) = 0$.

Comment: You meant $T(u_2) = 0$, right? Okay, but I still don't understand how to show that eigenvalues ​​are necessarily $\alpha, \alpha-1, \dots, \alpha- (n-1)$. It looks like they will be $\alpha, \alpha + 1, \dots, \alpha + n-1$.

Comment: @PaulichenT Yes, that's what I meant. And what's the difference between those two? For example, if $n = 3$ and the eigenvalues are $4,5,6$, then we can say that the eigenvalues are in the first form with $\alpha = 6$ and in the second form with $\alpha = 4$.

Comment: Right. It just seems to me that if $u$ is the eigenvector that generates the $T$ kernel, we will have a eigenvalue $\lambda$, and then to find the others it will be necessary to take an eigenvector $v \neq u$ with proper value $\alpha$. Won't that result in $ n + 1 $ eigenvalues? Well, we have $ \lambda $ associated with $u$, $ \alpha $ associated with $ v $, $ \alpha + 1 $ associated with $ T(v) $ ... and so on?

Comment: @PaulichenT If $u$ is the eigenvector associated with the largest of the eigenvalues of $A$, then we will have $T(u) = 0$. This means that there is no $(n+1)$th eigenvalue associated with $T(u)$.

Comment: Thankful, helped me a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119025/discussion-between-paulichent-and-ben-grossmann).